# Query all untagged RDS instances via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

Currently trying to round up untagged resources in our account.
So we need to tag all of our resources in amazon with "Project", so we'd easily know where it's for.

For EC2, we did this via `describe-instances --query "<query here>"`

However, in RDS `describe-db-instance`, tags are not even shown in the output. So we are unable to use `--query`.

Is there a way to do this for RDS CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to obtain a list of database instances, then loop through each instance and use [`aws rds list-tags-for-resource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/list-tags-for-resource.html) to retrieve the tags for the instance.

Alternatively, you might be able to use `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi` to retrieve tags from various different resources, rather than going to each service individually.

See: [resourcegroupstaggingapi — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/index.html)